# Copy file from remote Mac OSx to local Window 7 - error "The request is not supported"

Tags: c#, macos, permissions, cmd

I am trying to copy an existing file using C# from an open Mac OS x share to a Windows 7 share.

Using Windows file manager, I can browse the mac, and copy the files no problem.
Using Mac OS x file manager, I can browse the Windows share, and copy the files no problem.

When I tried using the standard C# File.copy(org, dst, true), it fails giving an error "part of path not found". I then tried opening a dos command window and copying the file over. This fails with a different error "The request was not supported". Thinking this is permissions or protocol related, I created a new test file and was successfully able to copy this over using the DOS prompt.

I then created a copy of one of the files I am unable to copy over, in case there was some strange lock on the file, but no luck either, it also sits and gives the same error (not supported).

I attach a screenshot of the Mac OS x LS listing to show file permissions, and also the error message I receive in the dos window.

- The first underline is the original file I can copy using the UI, but not with DOS
- The second underline is a COPY of the first underlined file - I cannot copy this with DOS either
- The third underline is the new file I created and I *can* copy this with DOS

I am assuming that if I can copy with DOS, then I can copy with C# File.Copy.

I would appreciate any assistance if anyone has seen this before.

[image: Request not supported]

Answer (score 0):

I never solved this issue, but did find a workaround .. instead of bringing files using my windows OS as the requester, I wrote a shell script on Mac OS X to rsync the files I wanted, and set these up as a cron job. Hope this helps someone else.